# Is the stack.yaml file supposed to be checked into version control?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm quite new to [stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack) and wondering whether to `git commit` or `.gitignore` that file.

What are the implications of either of these choices?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd say you should commit `stack.yaml`, as that makes it much easier to build your package in a reproducible way. That is particularly relevant if your repository is public, and if you use the more exotic kinds of extra-deps in `stack.yaml` (pointers to Git repositories, secondary cabal packages within your source tree, etc.).

A complementary observation is that we should still provide reasonable version bounds for dependencies in the .cabal file even if we are using stack, as doing otherwise would make life harder for people who don't use stack or have a set of packages different than the specified by `stack.yaml`.

Comment: What about `stack.yaml.lock`? Should that be committed too?

Comment: @davidA Those files contain supplementary information for specifying how to build the package, so it makes sense to commit them. (See also [the introduction to the doc page on lock files](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/lock_files/).)

Answer (score 2):

Yep. stack.yaml has a whole bunch of (not always necessary) fields such as the extra dependencies that matter for consistent builds. Check it in.

Comment: As long as you make sure that you don't edit stack.yaml besides what you get from stack init, then are you ok?