# Should stack.yaml.lock be checked into source control?

Tags: haskell, version-control, haskell-stack

Since stack v2, `stack` produces a `stack.yaml.lock` file.

Should this file be committed to source control, [like `stack.yaml`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31629081/40916)? Or should it be `.gitignore`d?

On the one hand it's generated content and isn't source, on the other hand it contains hashes of the dependencies from Hackage so it is necessary for a safe reproducible build..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. This is part of the reason that lock files exist: reproducible builds.

> These files can be stored in source control
> Users on other machines can reuse these lock files and get identical build plans given that the used local packages and local snapshots are the same on those machines

https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/lock_files/#lock-files

Answer (score 2):

It should be checked in - not doing so invalidates the whole purpose of the file (as is usual with .lock files)

Comment: Thanks! Note that your answer assumes familiarity with the usual for .lock files. But if I knew what the usual was, I probably wouldn't be asking..

Comment: Also, there have long been lock files with a very different purpose https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#Lock_files. Kind of a weird comment.